# Area in the plane described by inequalities

Tags: integration, inequality, area

An area in the plane is specified by the following inequalities:

$$x^2 \le y \le \frac6{\sqrt{x}}, \;  x\ge 1$$

How do I:

- draw this area?
- math this area?

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Sorry I'm so late :( Your question was perfectly understandable, which is the important thing; this is just an FYI about standard terminology: where you said "area" a mathematician would say "region", and where you said "math this area" a mathematician might say "solve for the region analytically" (That is what I would say at least: admittedly the vocabulary is less standard for this).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\text{For}\;\;x\ge 1\;\;,\;\;x^2\le\frac6{\sqrt x}\iff x^5\le 36\iff 1\le x\le\sqrt[5]{36}\;$$

And now just draw the functions $\;x^2\;$ and $\;\frac6{\sqrt x}\;$ ...

Comment: OK.. draw is done. Thx. Integration of x^2 is x^3/3+c and integration of 6/sqrt(x) is 12sqrt(x)+c. So x^3/3<=12sqrt(x) <==> x^3<=36sqrt(x) ... and now maybe stupid question :).. Why x^5<=36 ??

Comment: Good, @studisman .

Comment: I mean that correct is x^(5/2)<=36  .. (?)

Comment: $$x^2\le\frac6{\sqrt x}\iff x^2x^{1/2}\le 6\iff x^{5/2}\le 6\iff x^5\le 6^2=36$$